# value not stored in array ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I initialize  array

```
k = Array.new
```

then
something like

```
@m = Modul.where(:rfp_id => @rfp.id)
i = 0
for ii in @m
  k = ii.name.to_s
  i = i + 1
end
```

and then

```
 k.each do |a|
    ...
 end
```

but value is not stored in "k" how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try write clean code, for example:

```
Modul.where(:rfp_id => @rfp.id).pluck(:name).each do |name|
  puts name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this `k = ii.name.to_s` to `k.push(ii.name.to_s)`. It will work. You did not anywhere add the item `ii.name.to_s` to your array `k`. `k = ii.name.to_s` means in each loop iteration, you are going to reference a new string object to the local variable `k`. Read [`Array#push`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-push) to get introduce yourself to the method.

Don't need to write `k = Array.new`, rather`k = []` is enough for your purpose.